# PHP - Send async broadcast message to all clients

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently creating a website which is a bit like an image board, to which my friends can post various content.

I want to implement a function in PHP (serverside) and JavaScript/JQuery (clientside) to alert every client, which is currently viewing this site, when new content has been posted.

How do I implement such a 'broadcasting' function? Do I have to open a socket with JS and check the stream for any data, which my PHP page sends?
*(I have never used sockets with JS before, but I have the bad feeling, that I have to open a new port for every client, which openes my website ...)*

---

I would like to know, how you would implement such a method and if you have some reference article on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML 5 SSE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) would be the way to go I think.  This will have javascript listening for a message from the server.  You may optionally want to fall back to long-polling.   This page may be helpful [HTML5ROCKS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

> JS

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};

if(typeof(EventSource) === "undefined") {
    // NO SSE Support - Fall back to long-polling
}
```

> PHP (demo_sse.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bacsicaly, PHP & Javascript can not do that.

You can use NodeJS combine with PHP to do push notification to client

here is source code example on github: https://github.com/jeffasinger/simple-push

In php folder:

- listen.html is a client connect to server port 8000 and listen message from server
- trigger.php receive a message want to push to all client, after received message, make a CURL to /notify port 3000

In Node folder:

- Node.js listen two port
- 3000: listen local port, receive message want to push to all client
- 8000: listen public port, push all message to client